# Why img without position is like "absolute"?

Tags: html, css

Check this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/NUBXm/) :

#### HTML :

```
<div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 172px;">
    <img class="inf-image" align="right" src="http://www.ilritaglio.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/wee.jpg">
    
    <div class="inf-content">
        Hello        
    </div>   
</div>
```

#### CSS :

```
.inf-image
{
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px 8px 0px 0px;  
    width:20px;   
}

.inf-content {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height:50px;
}
```

looks like the div (which is relative) is under the image (which look absolute). Why? It should push the div over its height.

Comment: Why would you even be using `align="right"`? `align` is obsolete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating elements (like an `<img align="right">`) offset only the content of block elements, but not their backgrounds, so the red background of the `div` is seen under the image.

Comment: @markzzz I believe they behave the same way in many instances, including this one.

Comment: `align=right` is exactly the same as `float: right`. Inspect the applied styles in Chrome devtools or Firebug and you'll see the attribute triggers a `float: right` style.

Comment: Really? So what's the difference about float/align?

Comment: Float is CSS, align is a normal HTML attribute. Avoid the latter one in favor of the other.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about the CSS stacking context. If you give an element another `position` than `static` it will be moved to its own stacking context. From a logical point of view the `.inf-image { position: relative; }` is no longer a child of the parent `DIV` or a sibling to `.inf-content`. What you have now is a `DIV` with another `DIV` (the red one) inside. The image itself "hovers" in its own context right below the document root (`HTML`) and is just positioned relative to that element, which preceded it in the source.

Which is shown above which element can be determined by a combination of `position` and `z-index`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/stacking

Answer (score -1):

According to your css and html your div is positioned absolute while your image is positioned relative.  This is your problem.

```
<div style="position: relative; visibility: visible; width: 172px;">
    <img class="inf-image"src="http://www.ilritaglio.it/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/wee.jpg">

    <div class="inf-content">
        Hello        
    </div>   
</div>

.inf-image
{
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 3px 8px 0px 0px;  
    width:20px;
    right:0;
}

.inf-content {
    background-color: #FF0000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 150px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: The OP never said he/she has a problem…